# win 7 software raid 1, primary disk failed, what now?

Tags: windows-7, raid

I had a software RAID 1 between disc C: (the boot disk), and a spare disk. Now my main disk has died, and the spare disk won't boot.

How do I recover my computer? Do I get an empty disk and install windows 7 on it, then try to somehow sync it from my spare disk? Do I use some kind of a hack to make my second disk bootable?

Comment: Can you clarify if you had a software RAID between the DISK windows is on (which is the whole disk including bootsectors etc etc) or a RAID on VOLUME C:\  (which is only part of the disk, and which does not include bootsectors, nor other partitians sunch as /boot).

Comment: I had a 220 gig whole disk as primary, then the secondary disk was 1 tb, it had a partition that was synced with the main disk, and it had a second partition with the rest of the disk space.

Answer (score 3):

This is a common issue with Windows' soft RAID setups.

**Here's what you likely did wrong:**
The first issue you have is likely what @Hennes mentioned in his post.  Windows places the boot manager in a hidden partition.  Since Windows' soft RAID functionality operates at the volume level, not the disk level, it did not clone the boot partition to the second drive.

This would normally be an easy issue to fix if it weren't for the other issue you're running into...

When you created the RAID, the second disk probably had no partitions on it.  During the RAID creation process, Windows automatically upgrades both disks to be a Windows Dynamic Disk.

When you convert an existing disk with partitions on it to Dynamic, Windows creates a "fake" MBR on it so the BIOS can still boot the machine.  If a disk has no partitions, however, the fake MBR does not get created.  Since the BIOS does not understand dynamic disk data structures, there is no way for the BIOS to boot to the second drive -- even if you managed to create the boot partition that you're missing from the first drive.  Furthermore, Microsoft makes no tools that can create the fake MBR for you, and you cannot convert a dynamic disk back to basic if there are partitions on it.

**Here's how to fix it:**
Unfortunately, there is no easy way to restore your system back to the way it was before this happened.  Your best hope would be to just replace the failed disk and start fresh with a new copy of Windows 7.  Once it's running again you can import the other RAID volume and rescue your data.  Here's what you do:

- Replace the failed disk with a new one.  You can disconnect the 2nd RAID volume for safety's sake at this point but it's not necessary.
- Install Windows 7 to the new drive.  Let Windows Setup take care of partitioning the disk for you.
- Once Windows 7 is installed, reconnect the good RAID disk (if you disconnected it earlier) and go to Disk Administrator.  It will show the RAID volume as "Foreign Volume -- Offline".
- Right-click the volume and select Import.  It will warn you that the volume is missing one of its members, but you already know that so you can just ignore it.  Do not attempt to rebuild the array, sync it, or anything like that.  You just want to mount it so you can see the files on it.
- At this point, your former RAID volume should now have a drive letter.  You can just navigate to your old profile folder and copy your data off the drive.

---

**Future warning to others:**
Booting from a Windows software RAID is a broken feature and should not be done -- ever.  It does not behave the way you would expect a RAID-1 to operate.  The whole point of a RAID setup is to be able survive the failure of a single disk in the array.  This is not the case with Windows.  If the primary disk fails, the system is dead.  This is the exact opposite of how a RAID-1 is supposed to work, because now you have to recover your data from a non-working system, and that's what backups are supposed to be for, not RAIDs.

I would highly discourage anyone from using Windows' soft RAID feature on a boot volume.

Comment: I wonder if running `fixmbr` and `fixboot` on the drive will fix it.

Comment: It would not make the second volume bootable.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a full answer, and if I could place pictures in comments I would have done that.

What I am trying to figure out though is how did you windows system boot.

Tradiditional hardware RAID present a fake disk to the OS. Behind the scenes this virtual disk is often configured of an arrays of other physical drives. If you have a **hardware** RAID 1 and a disk fails then the OS should not even notice.

Now you wrote that you use **software** RAID 1. This means the translation between physical drives (or partitions) to a virtual drive is done in software. This obviously requires the OS to be up and running. Just how you get the OS up with drivers in order so that it is in a state where it can load drivers is a bit of a catch 22. Some of the solutions are:

1. Build the driver into the main kernal.
2. Boot from a non-RAID part (e.g. a different partition).
3. Boot from part of a mirror, preferably in read-only mode, and sync mirrors later.

Now what I have seen several times with windows is basically this:
[image]

It is a classical setup where a disk is partitioned with the old MBR scheme. Then windows is installed and it creates at least two partitions. One unencrypted boot partition, and one to put volume C:\ on.  The firmware (BIOS) powers up, performs POST and finds a bootable disk. The MBR on the disk indicates the 'system reserved' partiition as the active partition and it gets booted.  The windows bootloader on this partition takes over, decrypts the C:\ volume (if needed, e.g. when bitlocker comes into play) and continues to boot from that.

Now if you create such a traditional setup and add a second disk then you can go to diskmanagament, select volume C: by clicking on it and select 'add mirror'. This will mirror the selected volume. It will not create a mirror of the whole disk.

[image]

The latter is what I suspect that you did. In which case your data is still there, but you now have a non-bootable setup.

If this is the case than:

- Either reinstall windows, and restore lost data from backups.
- Or
  1: Make a fulll disk backup from the still working disk. (just in case).
  2: Actually test this backup!
  3: Install a fresh windows on another disk and try to add the old volume on the 1TB disk to the mirror.

Comment: 3: Install a fresh windows on another disk and try to add the old volume on the 1TB disk to the mirror. what is the mirror? add the disk 2 to itself? im so confused

Comment: **DO NOT** attempt to add the old volume as a mirror after you reinstall Windows.  That may destroy the contents of the second drive as well!  The failed drive should now be considered a broken mirror and should not be used. At all.  Your data is safe on the second volume.  Just pretend like the first disk is dead and don't attempt to rescue it.

Comment: Hence backup steps 1 and 2.   

Still, it would be nice to recover data from the broken mirror. Without ever having done that myelf I can not post sensible instructions on that though.

Comment: sorry for the confusion. im not asking what not to do, im asking what to do lol. so get a brand new disk 1, install windows on it, then put it into another computer and copy and paste disk 2 into it?

Comment: I updated my answer above to clarify the confusion. Basically @Hennes and I are saying the same thing.  You need a new disk and you'll have to reinstall Windows. You don't need to do it on another computer though.